# Information about button onclick in html with node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is my code:

file.html

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <input type="button" value="hello1" onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
   <input type="button" value="hello2" onClick="window.location.reload()" />
  </form>
 </body>
```

and this is my file.js

```
var http=require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    displayForm(res);
});

function displayForm(res) {
    fs.readFile('file.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
    });
 }

 server.listen(port, 'ip');
 console.log("Server running at http://ip:port/");
```

My question is: is it possible to distinguish in http.createServer(function(req,res){...}) what button is clicked? The question may seem stupid as both buttons do the same thing, but I need to be able to do a thing. Thank you all